# Error download when using python Wget lib

Tags: python, wget

Is there a way to restart the download if the download get stuck at XX%? I'm trying to do **scraping** and download quite a lot of files. I'm using the below code. It will solve connection error, but it won't restart any download if it get stuck.

```
    for element in elements:
        for attempt in range(100):
            try:
                wget.download(element.get_attribute("href"), path)
            except:
                print("attempt error, retry" + str(attempt))
            else:
                break
```

[image]

Comment: If below answer works for you, you can mark as correct answer.

Comment: It's not the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, it is.  There is no feature to do that.  I can remove the code, which is similar to the OPs code.  But the answer is correct. There is no other way to only request part of a file that has not been downloaded yet.

Comment: the problem is that it is stuck at the wget command, unless there is a way to check the % download at Time T and at Time T+delta, if the % download doesn't change, restart the wget command. Not too sure if there is such a way?

Comment: Check my edited answer with using requests library

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no feature to restart the download.  I looked at many examples of this package -> https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/83386/wget.download.  The page for the manual is gone and the pypi.org page does have have any info about a feature like this.

However, you can restart the download simply by adding another line to the `except`.  This code will work for you.

```
# Set some variables to end loop after download success
# The download loop will exit if failed 5 times
downloaded = False
attempts = 0
for element in elements:
    while not downloaded and attempts < 5:
        try:
            wget.download(element.get_attribute("href"), path)
            # Set downloaded flag to end loop
            downloaded = True
        except:
            print("attempt error, retry" + str(attempt))
            wget.download(element.get_attribute("href"), path)
                attempts += 1
```

Comment: Your code isn't right.  You need to have the retry loop INSIDE the `for element in elements`, so you're retrying a single file, and the way you have it, if there's an error in the retry, the app will explode, because the error is in the `except`.  His original was better, by going back to retry in the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach it to use **requests** library which is more popular.

```
import requests

def proceed_files():
    # Set some variables to end loop after download success
    # The download loop will exit if failed 5 times
    file_urls = ['list', 'of', 'file urls']
    for url in file_urls:
        downloaded = False
        attempts = 0
        while not downloaded and attempts < 5:
            if download_file(url):
                downloaded = True
            else:
                attempts += 1

def download_file(url):
    try:
        request = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        file_name = url.split('/')[:-1]
        open(file_name, 'wb').write(request.content)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: the problem is that it is stuck at the wget command, unless there is a way to check the % download at Time T and at Time T+delta, if the % download doesn't change, restart the wget command. Not too sure if there is such a way?

Comment: It should return an exception if download aborts unexpectedly (timeout for example), isn't it? Or it just saves what it could donwload so far w/o any exceptions or errors? Also as it's in WHILE loop it will not continue to the next instance in for loop unless it's downloaded = True and attemps are less than 5. So it will proceed to next instance only if it's downloaded or max number of attemps reached

Comment: there is no error (i.e. doesn't abort unexpectedly), you can see on the screenshot in my question. it's just get stuck at 2% without any timeout error and refused to do anything.

Comment: On the screenshot I can see that 2nd and 3rd files returned an exception (attempt error, retry 0). So if it stucks on 2% and not returning exception, then it's still waiting for response from server. Another way is to bind it os wget via subprocess in background, this is comletely different approach.

Comment: the attempt error is for me to know there is connection error to the file (i.e. not able to start downloading the file), it will try to connect again.

Comment: So it will return an exception, isn't it?

Comment: it will attempt to download again, up to 100 times, before return an exception.